# Copy xpath by finding element by tag name

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

So i was just trying to see if i could automate myself logging into the nike website when i realised that the xpath they use for the input changes every time you reload the page.
The only way i managed to find the element was by searching for it by the tag name input . However, when i then try to send the keys to it it gives me the error saying "element not visible". My question is how would i send the keys to it or is there a way of finding the xpath of an element each time i run the code by finding the element by the tag name (input)
Here is a copy of my code:

```
driver.get("https://www.nike.com/gb/en_gb/p/activity/login")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("input").send_keys("test")
```

And the website of the form is :https://www.nike.com/gb/en_gb/p/activity/login

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: I call your attention to [NIKE.COM TERMS OF USE](https://agreementservice.svs.nike.com/us/en_us/rest/agreement?agreementType=termsOfUse&country=US&language=en&mobileStatus=false&requestType=redirect&uxId=com.nike.commerce.nikedotcom.web): "*You agree not to ... download ... any  ... Content ... without NIKE's prior written consent, unless it is your own User Generated Content ...  You agree not to use any data mining, robots, scraping or similar data gathering methods.*"

Comment: i'm not gathering data. It's just an auto-filler that logs in for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to set the email and password with below code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']").send_keys("abcd")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys("abcd")
```

Comment: How did u get that xpath when i did inspect and copy as xpath i got "//*[@id="7f29c64a-8df6-4320-aefa-5c7c3a683fc9"]"

Comment: That won't work , because ID will get change everytime you load the page

Comment: Exactly. But i can't seem to find where you got the xpath from? When i select the box inspect and copy as xpath i get what i got above

Comment: So you have to write relative xpath , the way you are capturing the xpath is called " Absolute xpath" , it's not preferable.

Comment: how do you get that though sorry?

Comment: You can go through this link https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Comment: By writing proper xpath you can avoid can avoid lot of code , please go through above link

Comment: And never use any attributes which has number in it while framing locator

Comment: Okay thank you i know understand what you mean. That has helped save allot of confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cssSelector to find elements:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='emailAddress']")).send_keys("abcd");   
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']")).send_keys("abcd");
```

Using css-selector is faster than xpath and, in my opinion, it's also easier to declare and customize.